Custom Shortcuts in VSTO Addin - Application.OnKey: procedure call throws an error: "macros disabled or not available in the workbook"
I'm creating a VSTO Excel Add-in using VB.NET. I am trying to create custom shortcuts. Application.OnKey function has 2 inputs: key and procedure, I entered "^q", which means Control + q. In procedure i am entering the name of the procedure say for instance "HelloWorld". Pressing Ctrl +q gives me the attached error message box. I have attached the source code as well in case that helps as reference. If someone is aware about any alternate method of creating custom shortcuts in VSTO addin using VB.NET - that would be immensely helpful.
Error Message Box:

Cannot run the macro "HelloWorld".
The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Code
Private Sub ThisAddin_Startup() handles Me.Startup  
      Application.OnKey("^q", "HelloWorld") 
End Sub 

Public Sub HelloWorld  
      Msgbox("Hello World") 
End Sub

I tried incorporating the procedure names as a public sub which I thought would help but didnt. I also tried placing the procedure in the ThisAddIn.vb page instead of Ribbon1.vb page but to no avail.
